# Revealing Passwords in Azure Access Panel

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible in Azure AD to allow users to reveal passwords for SSO apps that use password vaulting in the Azure Access Panel (myapps.microsoft.com) or anywhere else? Or can Admins do the same for other users?

Some passwords are required by users when logging in to apps such as native mobile apps.

Any help would be great!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

By default, users cannot create app passwords. So to allow users to create app passwords, you have to enable this feature.

Check below URL and you'll know how to enable this function and also how to create app passwords for users/self-service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-whats-next#app-passwords